# How can i display items based on categories they belong to in a list in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am trying to display items in a list based on category of the items, an item can belong to a list of categories.

I want all products in a category to be grouped under that category and display as a list

Below is my response from API

```
{
  "menu_items": [
    {
      "categorys": [
        {
          "category_id": 1,
          "category_name": "Starters",
          "category_public_id": "1686264145980.3584",
          "created_at": "Fri, 09 Jun 2023 01:05:50 GMT",
          "description": "kmkmppp",
          "menu": "ff14ac35-a26d-4957-bb84-e55bcf04406a",
          "updated_at": "Fri, 09 Jun 2023 01:05:50 GMT"
        }
      ],
      "created_at": "Fri, 09 Jun 2023 01:05:50 GMT",
      "ingredients": ",p[ollp[lp[l",
      "is_active": "active",
      "itemId": 1,
      "item_image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dlh67cflz/image/upload/v1686264184/nova-ecommerce-products/jlazjhamnu6giineb2vb.jpg",
      "item_name": "grilled pork",
      "item_public_id": "1686264200760.36",
      "menus": [
        {
          "created_at": "Fri, 09 Jun 2023 01:05:50 GMT",
          "isActive": true,
          "menu_description": "kjmkmlk",
          "menu_id": 1,
          "menu_name": "christmas special",
          "menu_public_id": "ff14ac35-a26d-4957-bb84-e55bcf04406a",
          "menu_type": "dine_in",
          "merchant_id": "a46f810c-9f01-4eb2-b95a-2454959e4bbe",
          "updated_at": "Fri, 09 Jun 2023 01:05:50 GMT"
        }
      ],
      "price": 4500.0,
      "rating": null,
      "status": "in_stock",
      "updated_at": "Fri, 09 Jun 2023 01:05:50 GMT"
    },
    {
      "categorys": [
        {
          "category_id": 1,
          "category_name": "Starters",
          "category_public_id": "1686264145980.3584",
          "created_at": "Fri, 09 Jun 2023 01:05:50 GMT",
          "description": "kmkmppp",
          "menu": "ff14ac35-a26d-4957-bb84-e55bcf04406a",
          "updated_at": "Fri, 09 Jun 2023 01:05:50 GMT"
        }
      ],
      "created_at": "Wed, 21 Jun 2023 13:22:43 GMT",
      "ingredients": "with soy sauce, cabbage, onions",
      "is_active": "active",
      "itemId": 2,
      "item_image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dlh67cflz/image/upload/v1687343564/nova-ecommerce-products/qbdlhnesmzt9uoqffq7z.webp",
      "item_name": "grilled pork",
      "item_public_id": "1687343605822.5493",
      "menus": [
        {
          "created_at": "Fri, 09 Jun 2023 01:05:50 GMT",
          "isActive": true,
          "menu_description": "kjmkmlk",
          "menu_id": 1,
          "menu_name": "christmas special",
          "menu_public_id": "ff14ac35-a26d-4957-bb84-e55bcf04406a",
          "menu_type": "dine_in",
          "merchant_id": "a46f810c-9f01-4eb2-b95a-2454959e4bbe",
          "updated_at": "Fri, 09 Jun 2023 01:05:50 GMT"
        }
      ],
      "price": 25000.0,
      "rating": null,
      "status": "in_stock",
      "updated_at": "Wed, 21 Jun 2023 13:22:43 GMT"
    },
    {
      "categorys": [
        {
          "category_id": 2,
          "category_name": "Dinner",
          "category_public_id": "1687977074146.201",
          "created_at": "Wed, 28 Jun 2023 21:08:30 GMT",
          "description": "jnjniojiojo",
          "menu": "ff14ac35-a26d-4957-bb84-e55bcf04406a",
          "updated_at": "Wed, 28 Jun 2023 21:08:30 GMT"
        }
      ],
      "created_at": "Wed, 28 Jun 2023 21:08:30 GMT",
      "ingredients": "with minsed matooked and rice",
      "is_active": "active",
      "itemId": 3,
      "item_image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dlh67cflz/image/upload/v1687977153/nova-ecommerce-products/nocjoso04uur4fm8hkfd.webp",
      "item_name": "mushroom soup",
      "item_public_id": "1687977183611.3896",
      "menus": [
        {
          "created_at": "Fri, 09 Jun 2023 01:05:50 GMT",
          "isActive": true,
          "menu_description": "kjmkmlk",
          "menu_id": 1,
          "menu_name": "christmas special",
          "menu_public_id": "ff14ac35-a26d-4957-bb84-e55bcf04406a",
          "menu_type": "dine_in",
          "merchant_id": "a46f810c-9f01-4eb2-b95a-2454959e4bbe",
          "updated_at": "Fri, 09 Jun 2023 01:05:50 GMT"
        }
      ],
      "price": 45000.0,
      "rating": null,
      "status": "in_stock",
      "updated_at": "Wed, 28 Jun 2023 21:08:30 GMT"
    }
  ],
  "success": true
}
```

I am stack at the moment ,tried this but not producing expected results

```
 {Items?.menu_items?.map((items,index)=>(
                                  <div className='mb-8'>
                                    
                                    {items?.categorys.map(c=>(
                                      <>
                                       
                                      {c.category_public_id===items?.categorys[0]?.category_public_id && (
                                        <>
                                        <h2 className="text-lg font-semibold text-slate-900 py-2">{c.category_name}</h2>
                                         
 <ul role="list" className="-my-5 divide-y divide-gray-300">
 .....
</ul>
)}
   </>
                                            

  ))}
                                  
                                  
    
   </div>

   ))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking that starting off from categories rather then items would be good approach. Maybe get all categories in an array and map by them.

```
const categories = ["a", "b", "c"]
return ( categories.map( category => <ul className = "a"> {Items.map( item => {item.category === category ? <li> {item.whateverYouNeed} </li>})}
</ul> ) )
```

Alternatevly you can break it up with one more component. Make a categoryBlock 
 `const CategoryBlock = ({elements}) => { return (<div> { elements.map( e => <li>{e.whateverYouWant}</li> ) }</div>)` 
which takes in an array of items you want to display component and then do

```
categories.map( category => <CategoryBlock elements = {items.filter( item => item.category === category )}/> )
```

From your fetch response it seems like you have categories as a seperate document or table in your db so getting all the categories wouldn't be a problem